# Storyboard and AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios6, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

just ask a little problem i think... I using this code to open a storyboard configured in this mode: **Navigation Controller > TableView > DetailView**

Here's the code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *) launchOptions {

    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;

  PRPRecipesListViewController *controller = (PRPRecipesListViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
  controller.dataSource = [[PRPRecipesSource alloc] init];

  return YES;
}
```

Now the problem how can implement one View before the TableView to configure my storyboard in this mode: **Navigation Controller > HomeView with buttons (Push) > TableView > DetailView**

Any idea to resolve this is good.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up xcode on interface builder > select your **TableView**, on top bar of xcode
**Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller**